Clarification on Solving Two Equations to Find the Inradius of a Triangle
I am trying to find the inradius of a triangle with sides 5, 7, and 8. To approach this, I'm using the method of perpendicular segments from vertices to opposite sides and utilizing the area and equal product methods. I need some help confirming my calculations and understanding the process better.
Here's my approach:

Constructing Perpendiculars: From vertex ( A ) to side ( BC ), I've drawn a perpendicular segment ( AH ), and similarly from a point ( D ) on side ( BC ) (assuming ( D ) as the point where the inradius touches ( BC )), I've drawn a perpendicular segment ( DG ), which is the radius of the incircle.

Setting up Equations:

The equation based on Pythagoras' theorem for the triangle segment including ( AH ) is ( $5^2 - x^2 = y^2$ ) where ( x ) is the segment ( BH ), and ( y ) is ( AH ).
For the other segment, ( $7^2 - (8 - x)^2 = y^2$ ).


Solving the Equations:

By solving ( $5^2 - x^2 = y^2$ ) and ( $7^2 - (8 - x)^2 = y^2$ ), I found that ( x = $\frac{5}{2}$ ) and ( y = $\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}$ ).



Questions:

"Why can solving two simultaneous equations determine the appropriate values for (BH) and (AH)?"



Let's pretend that you don't know where $H$ is (similar to not knowing what $AH$ is), but we know of it lying on $BC$ with $AH \perp BC$. Consider the following:

Your first simultaneous equation, which is Pythagoras' theorem, fixes the location of $H$ to the red circle (the circle has diameter $AB$ from Thales' Theorem).
Your second simultaneous equation fixes the location of $H$ to the blue circle (having diameter $AC$).
Thus, $H$ must belong to the intersection of the two circles. Since $A \neq H$, we have only one point for $H$, and thus only one possible value for $AH$. Thus, two circles is enough to find where $H$ is, or alternatively, two equations is enough to find $AH$.
Now, with $AH$, we can just apply Pythagoras with the red circle equation to get $BH$.

Why can solving two simultaneous equations determine the appropriate values for (DG) and (AH)?What is the principle behind this?

Sorry, but I'm not sure whether you mean how to derive $DG$ and $AH$ from the two simultaneous equations, as $DG$ is not mentioned in the two simultaneous equations.

Sorry, I wasn't clear before. Why can solving two simultaneous equations determine the appropriate values for (BH) and (AH)?What is the principle behind this?

Let's see if my new argument helps.
